# Removing hyperlink from navigation pane in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperlink, navigation

I'm running into an issue with my beamer presentations. I'm using a presentation remote and it uses the tab key to toggle through the hyperlinks. It works great, except that the navigation pane links for all the subsections happen before the link on the slide. Is it possible to just make that navigation pane not have hyperlinks but everything else still have them? Most examples I've seen either just remove the bar or take all hyperlinks out of everything or just the table of contents slide.

MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Chart Toppers}
\begin{frame}{First Big Hit}
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \href{./ball.mp3}{``After the Ball''}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]{ball.jpg}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\NoHyper ... \endNoHyper` to temporarily disable hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}

\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{\NoHyper}{\endNoHyper}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}


\begin{document}

\section*{Chart Toppers}
\begin{frame}{First Big Hit}
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \href{./ball.mp3}{``After the Ball''}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight]{example-image-duck}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks!

Comment: @BenBradshaw You're welcome!